# ¿Cómo filtrar subdocumento referenciado Mongodb?

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, mongoose

¿Cómo puedo hacer un filtro en un subdocumeto referenciado en mongodb?

Problema: necesito hacer un filtrado en el documento category.

Controllador:

```
console.log(await Activity.find({}));
```

Respuesta del modelo:

```
 {
        _id: 5e0a360915b31c2f2c152a57,
        description: 'Venta de bienes muebles',
        tax_integrated: 7769.7,
        category: {
          _id: 5e0a3200c0dd7027849b64ba,
          category: 'K',
          anual_amount: 1726599.88,
          max_electricity: 20000,
          area: 200,
          max_rent_amount: 207191.98,
          sipa_amount: 1279.52,
          obra_social_amount: 689,
          __v: 0
        },
        __v: 0,
        id: '5e0a360915b31c2f2c152a57'
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Para hacer un filtrado sobre los campos de un subdocumento en MongoDB solo tendrias que hacerlo sela en formato string haciendo referencial al subdocumento y a su propiedad.

Suponiendo que quieres buscar por el campo ‘_id’ de ‘category’ tendias que hacer esta consulta:

```
Activity.find({“category._id”: “5e0a3200c0dd7027849b64ba”})
```